# htaccess or other method to prevent zip file download?

Tags: .htaccess, download, zip

Is there a way to prevent users to directly download zip files from server?
I try adding deny all in the htaccess but all that does it prevent the user from browsing the folder content.  They are still able to directly type in the browser http://site.com/file.zip and it would download..

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't put the zip file there in the first place. (For a serious answer you will probably have to describe the conditions when you *do* want to allow the file to be downloaded)

Comment: The people who can download it are authorized only through PHP sessions..So if they are logged in thus a session is created authorizing the user, then they can download it.  All others can't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If htaccess doesn't really work, then what about setting permissions to these files like to 600 or something?
I mean unix r/w permissions, you can change them via ftp etc.
And unless webserver works under your account, it won't be able to access them.

Comment: Ok, what I did was changed the uploaded zip file to a 640 chmod and that prevents direct access to the file from public and still allows full read/write to the owner which works out because the file is presented by a PHP script which "is" the owner...

Answer (score 2):

Use mod_rewrite to rewrite any url that ends in .zip to the page that does the authorisation and then in the authorisation page use `passthru()` to provide the zip file.

Something like this (might not work out of the box, merely to give you an idea):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.zip)$ authMe.php?url=$1
```

Have a read here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

And here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php

Comment: I tried a combination of this (rewriterule) still couldn't get it to work...I am still able to just paste the url to the file in the browser and download it...

Comment: Then your rewriterule doesn't match the url. Try something that matches everything and then see if you end up in the authMe page. For example: RewriteRule ^(*)$ authMe.php?url=$1
From there you then tighten the match rule to only zip files, or any file in a folder named XYZ: RewriteRule ^XYZ/([^/]*)$ authMe.php?url=$1

Answer (score 0):

You can password protect a directory and put the zipfile in that directory. A comprehensive guide how to do that is [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml).

Comment: I am looking for another way which just denies them...similar to a 404 if they try...

Comment: If you don't wat to password protect it and actually not make it reachable from outside at all, why do you have the file there? Just don't put it in your webroot and it won't be visible. Even if it isn't in your webroot, it can still be used by (PHP) scripts, so if you need it for that, you can still just move the file someplace else.

Answer (score 0):

What about this - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#files